# Performance cost of visiting a tuple at run-time this way

Tags: c++

I was shown this code

```cpp
template<typename F, typename ... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
void visit_tuple_impl(std::tuple<Ts...>& tup, F&&f, 
    std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::size_t idx) {
    auto check_call = [&](auto & elem, std::size_t I) {
        if (I == idx)
            f(elem);
    };

    (check_call(std::get<Is>(tup), Is), ...);
}

template<typename F, typename ... Ts>
void visit_tuple(std::tuple<Ts...>& tup, std::size_t idx, F&& f) {
    using TT = std::decay_t<decltype(tup)>;
    constexpr std::size_t size = std::tuple_size_v<TT>;
    auto idxs = std::make_index_sequence<size> {};
    visit_tuple_impl(tup, std::forward<F>(f), idxs, idx);
}

    void printComponents(uInt vectorId) {
        visit_tuple(data, vectorId, [&](auto &vec) {
            for(auto &elem : vec) {
                elem.print();
                std::cout << ' ';
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        });
    }
```

and the usage is like so:

```cpp
int vecId = 1;
ecsData.printComponents(vecId);
```

which means given a runtime variable `id`, every type inside the tuple can be visited at run-time using it in a for loop, as opposed as simply using `std::get<2>()` which do not accept a run-time variable as template argument.
So my question was "isn't the fold expression using `check_call()` lambda inside `visit_tuple_impl` doing a check for every id in the tuple every time it gets called?
Quoting the answer: `I wouldn't be surprised if it generates a lookup table that's O(1)`, but this seems more like a guess, so I am opening the question to you guys.

Is `check_call()` doing a check for every type inside the tuple for every call of `visit_tuple_impl` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly what the template will expand to. That's the direct, literal result of the template's expansion, in so many words. But whether or not this actually turns out to be the case, that's going to be a completely different story.

A compiler is allowed to do any optimization that has no observable results (provided that everything is within the bounds of defined behavior). Using a lookup table (and some bounds checking) has no observable results here, so your compiler may very well generate a lookup table-based code, if it's smart enough to figure out what's going on here, and it decides to do so.

The only way to know if your compiler is smart enough to figure out that this is what's going on, is to help your compiler as much you can (for example, explicitly specify `const std::size_t idx` as the function's parameter) and then look at the generated code.

Keep in mind that the result can vary depending upon the optimization level, and the tuple size. This is quite analogous to a plain `switch` with consecutive `case` values, where (typically) a compiler just generates a few comparisons, when there are a few values, and switches to a lookup table when the number of `case`s crosses some threshold.

But it should be obvious that the C++ standard does not require the compiler to execute every possible optimization that has no observable results, but is obvious to a human brain, and the compiler is not required to implement this particular optimization.

The short answer: look at what your compiler does, that's the only way to know.